# using context object with in the run method of Mapper class in Map-reduce Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Here is the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/com.cloudera.hadoop/hadoop-core/0.20.2-737/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Mapper.java#Mapper) for Mapper

```
public void run(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    setup(context);
    while (context.nextKeyValue()) {
      map(context.getCurrentKey(), context.getCurrentValue(), context);
    }
    cleanup(context);
  }
}
```

As you can notice, `context` is used both for `read` and `write`. How is it possible?
That is `context.getCurrentKey()` and `context.getCurrentValue()` are used to retrieve key and value pair from context and is passed to map function. Is it same `context` used for Input and Output?

Comment: `How is it possible?` Why shouldn't it be possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the same `context` is for both input and output. It stores references to `RecordReader` and `RecordWriter`. Whenever `context.getCurrentKey()` and `context.getCurrentValue()` are used to retrieve key and value pair, the request is delegated to `RecordReader`. And when `context.write()` is called, it is delegated to `RecordWriter`.

Note that `RecordReader` and `RecordWriter` are actually abstract classes.

Update:

`org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper$Context` implements `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.MapContext`, which again sub classes `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskInputOutputContext`

Look at the source of `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.MapContextImpl`. which is again a subclass of `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskInputOutputContextImpl` to see where exactly `Context` delegates input and output to `RecordReader` and `RecordWriter`.

Comment: can you direct me to code where context references both RecordReader and RecordWrier?

Comment: Yeah, `Mapper.Context` implements `MapContext`, which again sub classes `TaskInputOutputContext`. http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/TaskInputOutputContext.html

Comment: I still don't see how RecordReader and RecordWriter are referenced? That is, Context object should comprise of these so that read and write could be called. Source code might be helpful..?